Fourier transform of $y^2 p_{xx}(x,y)$ and $y^2 p_{yy}(x,y)$
What is the Fourier transform of $y^2 p_{xx}(x,y)$ and $y^2 p_{yy}(x,y)$?
Attempt:
I have a terrible memory, but here is what I recall. In one dimension, let $x$ the spatial variable and $k$ the Fourier variable. We have
$$\mathscr{F}[f''(x)]=-k^2 \hat{f}(k),$$
and, for any function $u(x)$,
$$\mathscr{F}[x^2  u(x)] = - \hat{u}''(k).$$
Therefore, letting $u(x)=f''(x)$, by combining these, we obtain
$$\mathscr{F}[x^2 f''(x)]=\mathscr{F}[x^2 u(x)] = -\hat{u}''(k),$$
but
$$\hat{u} = \mathscr{F}[u]=\mathscr{F}[f''(x)]=-k^2 \hat{f}(k),$$
therefore
$$ \mathscr{F}[x^2 f''(x)] = -\frac{d^2}{dk^2} [-k^2 \hat{f}(k)]$$
$$ = \frac{d}{dk}[2k \hat{f}(k)+k^2 \hat{f}'(k)]$$
$$ = 2\hat{f}(k)+2k \hat{f}'(k)+ 2k \hat{f}'(k)+k^2 \hat{f}''(k)$$
$$ = k^2 \hat{f}''(k) +4k \hat{f}'(k)+2\hat{f}(k).$$
It's been awhile since I've dealt with multivariate Fourier transforms, so I am having some trouble seeing how to generalize this. I could probably figure it out myself with a little nudge (or more coffee)... If someone is compelled to write out the general rule, say of computing $\mathscr{F}[x_i^n \partial_j^m p(x_1,\dotsc, x_d)]$ that would be above and beyond what I could ask for.
Update:
I thought a little harder and I think we can say that for $u(x,y)$, we have
$$\mathscr{F}[y^2 u(x,y)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty y^2 u(x,y) e^{-i(k_1 x+k_2 y)} dx dy$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty y^2 u(x,y) e^{-ik_2 y}dy\right] e^{-ik_1 x}dx$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^\infty-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial k_2^2} \mathscr{F}_y[u(x,y)] e^{-ik_1 x}dx$$
$$ = -\frac{\partial^2}{\partial k_2^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathscr{F}_y[u(x,y)] e^{-ik_1 x} dx$$
$$ = -\frac{\partial^2}{\partial k_2^2}  \mathscr{F}[u(x,y)],$$
right? If this is true, then we can easily derive that
$$\mathscr{F}[y^2 p_{xx}(x,y)] = -\frac{\partial^2}{\partial k_2^2} (-k_1^2 \hat{p}(k_1,k_2)),$$
etc.
If someone can verify this, I would be very appreciative.

It appears you have it correct.

We can say that for $u(x,y)$, we have
$$\mathscr{F}[y^2 u(x,y)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty y^2 u(x,y) e^{-i(k_1 x+k_2 y)} dx dy$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty y^2 u(x,y) e^{-ik_2 y}dy\right] e^{-ik_1 x}dx$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^\infty-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial k_2^2} \mathscr{F}_y[u(x,y)] e^{-ik_1 x}dx$$
$$ = -\frac{\partial^2}{\partial k_2^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathscr{F}_y[u(x,y)] e^{-ik_1 x} dx$$
$$ = -\frac{\partial^2}{\partial k_2^2}  \mathscr{F}[u(x,y)],$$
thus, we can easily derive that
$$\mathscr{F}[y^2 p_{xx}(x,y)] = -\frac{\partial^2}{\partial k_2^2} (-k_1^2 \hat{p}(k_1,k_2)),$$
etc, by combining properties of Fourier transforms. I appreciate @Mark Viola for checking this.
By generalizing this, we obtain the rule:
$$\mathscr{F}[x_l^n \partial_j^m p(x_1,\dotsc, x_d)]=i^n\frac{\partial^n}{\partial k_l^n} [(i k_j)^m \hat{p}(k_1,\dotsc, k_d)]$$
